# shell bash code not run with no error warning

Tags: linux, apache, bash, shell, curl

I write some shell bash to check if apache has wrong? I use curl my one page, if head return `200 ok`, it seems apache run well, else, do  `service httpd restart`, To monitor whether the script, i write some the run date and status into some log(1.txt).

apache.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
curl -I http://www.mydomain.com/check.php 2>/dev/null | head -1 | grep -q " 200 OK"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then echo "ok $(date)" >> 1.txt; else service httpd restart;echo "restart $(date)" >> 1.txt; fi
```

crontab

```
*/6 * * * * /bin/sh /home/username/apache.sh >/dev/null 2>&1
```

But yesterday, my apache still gone, (child process xxxx still did not exit, sending a SIGKILL).

I tried in ssh command line `/bin/sh /home/username/apache.sh`, no log has been writing(1.txt is empty) with no error warning.

Where is the problem? thanks.

Comment: Check your syserr log in `/var/logs` and try giving full path of curl like `/usr/local/bin/curl` or whatever you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try a simpler script like this:

```
rc=$(curl -Is -w '%{http_code}' -o /dev/null http://www.mydomain.com/check.php)
if [ $rc -eq 200 ]; then
    echo "ok $(date)" >> 1.txt
else
    service httpd restart
    echo "restart $(date)" >> 1.txt
fi
```

Comment: error in line 1  `")syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is "` and how to write a shell without change line? I write some format like you, always get `syntax error near unexpected token 'fi'` thanks.

Comment: Probably `[[` isn't available or you're not using BASH. Try edited code now.

Comment: `syntax error near unexpected token 'fi'`, i edited in dreamweaver cs4.

Comment: Weird, Try running `curl -Is -w '%{http_code}' -o /dev/null http://www.mydomain.com/check.php` command and see what output you get.

Comment: Yes that is what it is supposed to do. After that you can keep your old `if/else` but with a different condition `$rc -eq 200`

Comment: but why i always get `syntax error near unexpected token 'fi'? so can you write `if else fin` in one line?(no newline), thanks.

Comment: Yes you can use: `if [ $rc -eq 200 ]; then echo "ok $(date)" >> 1.txt; else service httpd restart;echo "restart $(date)" >> 1.txt; fi`  Probably you were missing some semi colon.

Comment: `: integer expression expectedne 3: [: 200`

Comment: Try string comparison: `if [ "$rc" = "200" ]; then echo "ok $(date)" >> 1.txt; else service httpd restart;echo "restart $(date)" >> 1.txt; fi`

Answer (score 0):

The service httpd restart will exit even when some of the child processes are still running - hence the msg child process xxxx still did not exit, sending a SIGKILL.
I have noticed this before, with db heavy websites (drupal, wordpress etc) and the solution is to stop apache, check if there are still child procs about and kill them, then restart apache.

```
service httpd stop
iter=0
# wait 30 seconds for any child procs to exit
while pgrep httpd
do
    iter=$(( iter + 1 ))
    if [ $iter -gt 6 ]
    then
         break
    fi
    sleep 5
done
# ok, I've finished waiting I'm going to kill 'em all
if pgrep httpd
then
    pkill -9 httpd
fi
service httpd start
```